# Running Cygwin Screen as a standalone program?

Tags: windows, cygwin, gnu-screen

Would it be possible to separate Screen from Cygwin, and run it without running Cygwin first? If not, are there any alternatives to screen on Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen` on Cygwin uses the Cygwin dll, so while you could make a minimal configuration with just a couple of files, that would be "running Cygwin".  Likewise, `screen` is only useful with a shell — the same story (for instance `bash`, again using the Cygwin dll).

A quick check for alternatives seems to show that you would not succeed with

- [MinGW](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/Getting-Gnu-Screen-to-compile-under-mingw-td3523.html)
- [Msys2](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages)

Regarding `screen` on Cygwin, this has been discussed at length in *[Terminal Multiplexer for Microsoft Windows - Installers for GNU Screen or tmux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473384/terminal-multiplexer-for-microsoft-windows-installers-for-gnu-screen-or-tmux)*, although not as a "standalone" program.

Comment: I tried to run it with the DLL's and screen said that the '/tmp/uscreens' couldn't be found, so it doesn't work independantly.

Comment: yes - but providing directories to appease `screen` might be one of the simpler problems to resolve.

Comment: How would you create the linux-style directories on Windows? I didn't think it was possible because it couldn't find `/tmp/uscreens`

Comment: When you install Cygwin, it does create the directory (as well as setting a registry value that tells where Cygwin is installed).  The short answer is that the Cygwin DLL uses existing directories and the registry value to decide how to manage the directories.

Comment: `/tmp` exists under the Cygwin install dir. If you add this line to `/etc/fstab` (also under Cyginw install dir): `none           /tmp             usertemp  binary,posix=0       0 0`, `/tmp` will point to your Windows user TEMP dir. When I ran `screen` first time, it created `/tmp/uscreens`, when trying to do `screen -r` it complained about permissions (must be 777) on that dir, though. For some reason, though, after detaching I can only reattach (`screen -r`) if I connect to Cygwin via PuTTY (either through local SSH or through cygtermd), not from mintty or ConEmu.